# How can I change the link color using SwiftyMarkdown?

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm using **SwiftyMarkdown**. I wrote the following code but I couldn't change the link color.
How can I change the color of it?

```
private func markdown(_ markdownText: String) -> SwiftyMarkdown {
    let md = SwiftyMarkdown(string: markdownText)
    md.setFontColorForAllStyles(with: .white)
    md.link.color = .red
    return md
}

func sample() {
    label?.attributedText = markdown("sample [url](http://google.com)").attributedString()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, SwiftyMarkdown's method of setting the `foregroundColor` of the range of links does not seem to work consistently.

[As this GitHub issue suggests](https://github.com/SimonFairbairn/SwiftyMarkdown/issues/7), **you should use a `UITextView`** instead of a `UILabel` and **set the `linkTextAttributes`** of the text view.

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red]
```

**Result:**

[image: screenshot of the result]

If you want to underline links, append an `underlineStyle` to `linkTextAttributes`:

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red,
                               NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle.rawValue: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
```

**Result:**

[image: screenshot of the result (the link is underlined)]

Comment: Thank you he4kman. I see. I can set them dilectly. It worked fine. Thank you very much.